# Assets.xcassets in Watch Extension in WatchOS 2

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchos-2, xcasset

What is the purpose of `Assets.xcassets` in Watch Extension in WatchOS 2? What images should be included in these assets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Assets.xcassets` in the WatchKit extension contains [`CLKImageProvider`](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/ClockKit/Reference/CLKImageProvider_class/index.html) images used by circular, modular, and utilitarian complications. The images are template images that have a tint color applied to them prior to display.

Since they are part of an asset catalog group, you would need to specify the group name when referring to those images:

```
template.imageProvider = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: UIImage(named: "Complication/Circular")!)
```